# CodeIgniter - pre select a value from dropdown based on link clicked

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, dropdownbox

I'd like some help please. I'm having this link

```
<?php echo anchor('contact#apply', 'Apply for Job'); ?>
```

in my `Careers` page /view, which redirects to the `Contact`, where I have this dropdown menu in my form

```
$reasons = array(
            'request-feedback'  => 'I'd like more information please',
            'request-a-demo'=> 'I want a demo of your services', 
            'work-with-us'  => 'I am interested in working for youy company', // * this is the option I'm interested in
);
<?php echo form_label('Reason for getting in touch with us', 'reason'); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('reason', $reasons, null, 'class="form-control"'); ?> // * when user applies for job should have the 3rd option pre selected instead of null
<?php echo form_error('topic'); ?>
```

What I'd like to do is when a user clicks on that link to redirect him to the contact form and have the `work-with-us` option pre selected, **but only in this case**, in any other case the default should be the first one.

How can I do this ?

Note: both `Careers` and `Contact pages` have this structure

```
careers/index // i.e. controller/method
contact/index
```

so basicaly there are two different controllers

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter select\_value in form\_dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445982/codeigniter-select-value-in-form-dropdown)

Comment: @Peter I'm basicaly asking how to pre select a value only if this link is clicked, not in all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in this way. In the url, there should be an 'id' to identify that it coming from 'contact/apply' link.You can do it in this way

```
<?php echo anchor('contact/apply?id=contact', 'Apply for Job'); ?>
```

in your 'apply' method in 'contact' controller, it can check the id

```
public function apply(){
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
     $id=$_GET['id'];
     if($id=='contact'){
      $selected='work-with-us';
     }
     else{
       $selected='request-feedback';
     }
 }
 else{
   $selected='request-feedback';
 }

  //the data send to view page
  $data['selected_val']=$selected;
  $this->load->view('view_page', $data);
}
```

then in your 'view_page' in the relevant drop down, it can set the selected value

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('reason', $reasons, $selected_val, 'class="form-control"'); ?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yeap! Its working! one additional thing.. When I was selecting the `work-with-us` option, I also display an input field for uploading a CV, I did this with jquery `on.change` event .. How can I display this field in this case too ?

Answer (score 0):

Way to the second case..

```
<?php if($selected_val!='work-with-us'){ ?>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#depend_on_select").hide();
     });
   </script>
<?php } ?>

<div id="depend_on_select">
   <input type="file" name="cv">
</div>
```

In here the div that contain cv will show only $selected_val='work-with-us'.